# Does Python-import import lists?

Tags: python, import, python-import

Hi i have 2 Python Files in the same directory:

**paths.py:**

```
import os


def Listfilesindirectory():
    
    os.chdir(input('Working Directory: '))

    pathlist = os.listdir()

    for i in range(len(pathlist)):
        print(pathlist[i] + '\n')
```

**main_hash.py:**

```
import defs
import paths

paths.Listfilesindirectory()



hashlist = []

for n in range(len(pathlist)):
    hashlist[n] = defs.hash_file(pathlist[n])

print(hashlist)
```

First I import the paths.py file in main_hash.py; than in main.py I execute (is execute the right term??) the Listfilesindirectory that i defined in paths.py. No problem until here, it gets executed flawlessly. Than i want to use the list "pathlist" that i initiated in paths.py. But i get the following error code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/kyilmaz/Documents/Python/main_hash.py", line 10, in <module>
    for n in range(len(pathlist)):
NameError: name 'pathlist' is not defined
```

Shouldn't "pathlist" be imported in main.py? I also tried: from paths import pathlist. Doesn't work.

Comment: This is issue with the scope, not with the import. The scope of `pathlist` is local for `Listfilesindirectory`. Your function should return it if you want to use it. And then bind the returned object to a name when you call it.

Comment: @buran Why and how do we bind the returned object to a name?

Comment: That is exactly what you ask about in the answer `Listfilesindirectory`  returns `pathlist`. Then when you call it `pathlist = paths.Listfilesindirectory()`. Note that there are two different names `pathlist`. One is with local scope inside the function (and returned). the other is in the global scope of module `main_hash`. They are different.

Answer (score 1):

You should change your code like the below code.

Paths.py

```js
import os


def Listfilesindirectory():
    os.chdir(input('Working Directory: '))

    pathlist = os.listdir()

    for i in range(len(pathlist)):
        print(pathlist[i] + '\n')

    return pathlist
```

main_hash.py:

```js
import paths

pathlist = paths.Listfilesindirectory()

hashlist = []

for n in range(len(pathlist)):
    hashlist[n] = defs.hash_file(pathlist[n])

print(hashlist)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It works now! Can also please explain me why we do the: pathlist = paths.Listfilesindirectory() ?? Listfilesindirectory() just a def and why do we put it inside pathlist?